# How do I tell re to return all the digits when \d returns nothing?

Tags: python, scrapy, python-3.6

```
def parse(self, response):
    for line in response.css('small'):
        yield {
            'seats': line.css('*').get().re('\d')
        }
```

this code puts mothing in my file

but this code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for line in response.css('small'):
        yield {
            'seats': line.css('*').get()
        }
```

(same but without the re)

puts many stuff in the file including a lot of digits. so why doesn't the first code give me just the digits?

Comment: That does not look like standard Python functions. What imports are you using? [Edit] your question and make it a [mcve] so we can help you out.

Comment: .. Does that library you are using specify that you do not need string escaping for the backslash in your re? It is part of Python's string handling so it would be very difficult to circumvent.

Comment: I am using scrapy, I set the tag, sorry for mot saying

Comment: if you are looking for how `re` works, `\d` will match only numbers in the lines and nothing else. I am not fully understanding you requirement here, but `regex` pattern matching might be what you should be looking into. maybe you need to use `.re(r'(\d+)')`

Comment: `'\d'` should be `r'\d'` or `'\\d'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you incorrectly combine `get()` and `re()` methods. [`re()`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions) is a method of `Selector` while [`get()`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1) returns the textual data from selector. Thus, you need to apply `re()` to the selector itself:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for line in response.css('small'):
        yield {
            'seats': line.css('*').re(r'\d+')
        }
```

Also, note using raw string `r'\d+'` for the regex pattern and `\d+` as the actual pattern to return all the digits.